# Grau de agrupamento de turmas

Tags: r

Eu tenho várias turmas e cada uma dessas turmas são compostas por dezenas de alunos, e a cada ano esses alunos mudam de turma. Assim, gostaria de calcular o grau de agrupamento que uma turma mantem de um ano para o outro de uma forma automática. Por exemplo, no ano de 2015 uma escola possui duas turmas de 1ª série, conforme abaixo:

```
turma1a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')   
turma1b <- c('K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U')
```

E no ano de 2016 esses alunos passaram para a 2ª série no ano de 2016 indo para duas novas turmas de maneira aleatória, conforme abaixo:

```
turma2a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N')  
turma2b <- c('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
```

Dessa forma, gostaria de determinar que a `turma1a` foi 60% para a `turma2a` e que a outra foi 63,63% para o `2b`.

Eu tentei fazer por intersecção no `R`, sabendo quais são as turmas mais semelhantes, mas eu precisaria fazer com dezenas de turmas comparadas mutuamente.

```
   turma1a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
   turma1b <- c('K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U')
   turma2a <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N')
   turma2b <- c('O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J')
   intersect(turma1a, turma2a)
   [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F"
```

Com esse `script`, encontro os alunos em comum, mas eu precisaria que fosse automático, pois preciso analisar dezenas de turmas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma possível solução é usar um duplo ciclo com `lapply` para criar uma lista de alunos comuns e respetivas proporções.
Para isso, é melhor ter as turmas juntas em listas.

```
lista_t1 <- list(turma1a, turma1b)
names(lista_t1) <- c("turma1a", "turma1b")
lista_t2 <- list(turma2a, turma2b)
names(lista_t2) <- c("turma2a", "turma2b")
```

Agora usamos os ciclos `lapply` nestas listas.

```
resultado <- lapply(lista_t1, function(x)
                lapply(lista_t2, function(y) {
                    int <- intersect(x, y)
                    list(comuns = int, prop = length(int)/length(x))
                })
            )
```

É claro que deve haver muitas outras formas de resolver este problema. Esta é só uma delas e talvez que a estrutura de dados de `resultado` não seja a melhor. (É sempre complicado trabalhar com listas e sub-listas, etc.)

Nota:
É talvez melhor também automatizar algumas operações de criação das listas de turmas. Por exemplo, os nomes das turmas podem ser atribuídos com

```
names(lista_t1) <- ls()[grep("turma1", ls())]
names(lista_t2) <- ls()[grep("turma2", ls())]
```

o que evita ter de escrever todos os nomes.